# How to create Up and Down Methods using migrations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am new to Code first, can you tell me how i can have all Up and Down methods for all tables in the database like below(given for one table)

```
public partial class abc: DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.UserTasks", "ServiceTechReason", c => c.Long());
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.UserTasks", "ServiceTechReason");
        }
    }
```

i want all three types for a table viz .cs , .Designer.cs , .resx.

2) Can you explain the above example, i pick it from somewhere on internet i was searching for this but found nothing. is abc is my table name in database?

Provide me link if it is already answered.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @scheien i already tried those commands they do not automatically override up and down methods for a table

Answer (score 1):

Creating migrations is done by running the command `Add-Migration AddedServiceTechReason`.

This assumes that you have already enabled migrations using the `Enable-Migrations` command.

To apply the current migration to the database, you'd run the `Update-Database`. This command will apply all pending migrations.

The point of Code-First migrations is that you make the changes you want to your Entity(ies), and then add a new migration using the `Add-Migration` command. It will then create a class that inherits `DbMigration`, with the `Up()` and `Down()` methods filled with the changes you have made to your entity/entities.

As per @SteveGreenes comment: It does pick up all changes to your entities, so you don't need to run it once per table/entity.

*If you want to customize the generated migration files, look under the section "Customizing Migrations" in the article listed.*

All these commands are run in the package manager console.

> *View -> Other windows -> Package Manager Console*.

[Here's a great article from blogs.msdn.com that explains it in detail.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: I already tried these command they do not add Up and Down methods for a table

Comment: Then you need to provide more context to your question. You did not say that you had tried those commands. What happens when you try the `Add-migration` command?

Comment: meh!! my bad i just run `Add-Migration abc -ProjectName main.project -StartUpProjectName pqr` and it worked  but do i have to ran this for every table, i mean can i have all this in one command. it ask for name if i run it like this 'Add-Migration -ProjectName main.project -StartUpProjectName pqr'

Comment: Add-Migration will pickup all the changes from your model since the last migration, so no, you don't run it per table.